# Why do setter methods in an entity return $this?

Tags: entities, 9

Writing a custom entity type I noticed that all setter methods in entity classes are returning $this after changes, as methods modify the object and so object will definitely being modified, then

> what is the propose of returning the objects? is it a best practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's for chaining, e.g.

```
$an_object
  ->doSomething()
  ->doSomethingElse()
  ->andSomethingElse();
```

Whether it's best practice is up for debate, there's no right or wrong answer to that. Some like it because it looks nice (so called [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)), some don't like it because, well because many reasons.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not for some interesting opinions.

Answer (score 5):

The benefit is, you can chain methods, like saving the entity after you have set values:

```
$entity->set('label', 'foo')->save();
```

Caveat: [save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Asave) doesn't return the object, but the result of the save operation  as integer.